# Magento 2 - How to revert model save in afterSave method

Tags: magento2

I have two tables "first_table" and  "second_table".
I am using afterSave method in "first_table" model class like bellow

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

/**
 * FirstTable model
 *
 */
class FirstTable extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Model construct that should be used for object initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\FirstTable::class);
    }

    /**
     * Processing object after save data
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        // some code
        parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

In after save function, I want to take current record ID (By $this->getId()) and save some data in "second_table".
Now what I want is if "second_table" insert goes fail, I want to revert the "first_table" insert and redirect user again to edit page. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the second table data in the beforeSave function?

If it fails, you can throw an exception that will prevent the save first table data to happen.

Once the above is implemented, you will need a try/catch block when you call the first table save method to wrap the error message and that should allow the user to try to save the data again.

Comment: I can't have ID of first table in beforeSave() in the case of new record

Comment: Of course, you want to use transaction. Apologies, I should have seen this anyway